# How to test your django model using shell

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-shell

I am trying to learn Django and have a very simple question that I am not able to get around with. I have coded my Django model as:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    STATES = (
        ('STARTED', 'started'),
        ('IN_PROGRESS', 'running'),
        ('FINISHED', 'completed'),
        ('ERROR', 'Error'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    temp  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    current_run = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    completion_percentage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATES, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have regenerated the db and now I want to use it Django views. But, before that is there a way to test it using python manage.py shell?

I am trying to do:

```
d_ = Work.objects.create(owner='admin')
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'admin'": "Work.owner" must be a "User" instance.
```

Currently, I have userid as 'admin' in Users.
I have tried doing few things to get around the error but I keep getting some kind of error because of the owner field (which is set to foreign key of auth.User).

Any help will be appreciated here. Thank you!

Comment: What's confusing you about that message? You need an actual User instance, not a username.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right. I tried user instance but i was doing something wrong. Now, I get it and below answer also helps me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an actual user object. Try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
admin = User.objects.get(username='admin')
d_ = Work.objects.create(owner=admin)
```